# Understanding function pointers and insertion-sort in C

Tags: c

I am trying to implement an insertion sort with parameters very similar to the built in qsort in C, but I'm struggling to find the right approach as I am failing in completely grasping function pointers. How would I go about rewriting this as an insertion sort (with function pointers?)

```
static void sort(char *array, size_t size, int (*cmp)(void*,void*), int    
begin, int end) {
   if (end > begin) {
  void *pivot = array + begin;
  int l = begin + size;
  int r = end;
  while(l < r) {
     if (cmp(array+l,pivot) <= 0) {
        l += size;
     } else if ( cmp(array+r, pivot) > 0 )  {
        r -= size;
     } else if ( l < r ) {
        swap(array+l, array+r, size);
     }
  }
  l -= size;
  swap(array+begin, array+l, size);
  sort(array, size, cmp, begin, l);
  sort(array, size, cmp, r, end);
   }
}

void qsort(void *array, size_t nitems, size_t size, int (*cmp)(void*,void*)) {
   sort(array, size, cmp, 0, nitems*size);
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Start by implementing the insertion sort function using normal comparison operators. Then when you get that to work replace the comparison with calls to the function.

Comment: Too broad / unclear what you're asking. And confusing, you are already using function pointers.

Comment: `else if ( l < r ) {
        swap(array+l, array+r, size);
     }` is unreachable code. And I don't think this code is of **insertion sort** in any sense. Firstly, you should use correct insertion sort code and later worry about the use of function pointers.

Comment: This sorting code looks something like **quicksort**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to replace the comparison operator in the insertion sort algorithm by your compare function. Your function `insertionSort` should look like this.:

```
void insertionSort(void *array, size_t nitems, size_t size, int (*cmp)(void*,void*))
{
    size_t i, j;
    for ( i = 1; i < nitems; i++ )
    {
        j = i;
        while ( j > 0 && cmp( (char*)array+j-1, (char*)array+j ) > 0 )
                      // ^^^ call of cmp instead of operator >
        {
            swap( (char*)array+j-1, (char*)array+j, size );
            j--;
        }
    }
}
```

I used this source for the [Insertion Sort](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Insertion_sort) algorithm.

If you like to pass the swap function as a paramter too, you can do it like this:

```
void insertionSort(void *array, size_t nitems, size_t size, int (*cmp)(void*,void*), void (*swapdata)(void*,void*,size_t))
{
    size_t i, j;
    for ( i = 1; i < nitems; i++ )
    {
        j = i;
        while ( j > 0 && cmp( (char*)array+j-1, (char*)array+j ) > 0 )
        {
            swapdata( (char*)array+j-1, (char*)array+j, size );
            j--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh thank you, I'm now trying to implement the swapping action within the insertionSort function without the swapping function. How would I go about doing that?